# Remote Desktop Protocol Provider API

Tags: rdp

I'm trying to implement "Remote Desktop Protocol Provider API". And i'm see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd920052(v=vs.85).aspx 
but,  it seems like information in this topic is incomplete.
I've tried to create my own provider. I've created in-proc COM-server with class, that implements IWrdsProtocolManager interface, registered it as shown in this topic, restarted Remote Desktop Services and nothing have happened! Then, I've tried to rewrite LoadableProtocol_Object value of Rdp-Tcp key to CLSID of my COM-class. Nothing happened again! When I'm trying to create my ProtocolManager by hands using CoCreateInstance, I works as expected, but how can I make Terminal Services do the same?  There are no errors in Event Viewer, no message boxes with information of what i'm doing wrong. Please, publish more detailed information of creating and registering protocol providers, if possible.

Who can help me?

Comment: I wish I could... I'm implementing this myself at the moment. Perhaps I'll make a tutorial when I'm done...? There are some fiddly bits to it, particularly working out how to handle the one or two calls that you can't reply instantly to. My strategy at the moment is spinning up a thread for each connection. It's just so sparse! I'm also very disappointed I can only do username/password auth, rather than provide a token obtained through SSO with SSPI for example.

Comment: Did any of you guys succeed at it? I am looking into it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the machine that you want to load the protocol object is domain-joined and has Remote Desktop Services (session / licensing) enabled -- you're not getting an error message, but the termsrv library is preventing the custom protocol handler from running because it's not an RDS host.